# Meanings of the word promote

Tags: meaning

[Finlandia takes their pure water sources so seriously, they promote stunts like this to raise awareness](http://www.eater.com/drinks/2015/11/25/9784954/spirits-water-purity-water-sources) [image]

According to merriam-webster dictionary the word promote has the following meanings:
- to help (something) happen, develop, or increase
- to contribute to the growth or prosperity.

So, does that mean that the company finances sport events like the one from the picture? or that it just uses such pictures for advertising its product?

Comment: This is General Reference. [**Promote**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/promote) ***Support or actively encourage** (a cause, venture, etc.); further the progress of*

Comment: "Promote" can mean anything from completely setting up the above shot to simply contributing $50 to support the printing of some fliers.

Answer (score 2):

It means that they support and publicise such events.

It can have many more specific terms, for instance in the job title "Music Promoter", where this is generally tied to particular aspects of supporting and publicising.